# J1939 - Source Address field and Address Claim for a diagnostic/scanner board

Tags: can, protocol

I have a board that include CAN hardware, I would like to use it to scan some PGNs of the J1939 protocol on a fork-lift.
This is the packet:

[image]

Below we have the the PGN 65262. Considering that all the hardware wiring connections is ok and working, what happens if I simply transmit with my board a request packet (RTR bit = '1') for PGN 65262 with a random value (like 254) at the Source Adress field? Will the board receive a response for the requested PGN?

[image]

If not, I think the board will need to claim an address, but how this occur in details? How is the complete procedure for claiming address on the J1939 bus, including the PGN for this purpose? I didn't find a very clear explanation on the web, I have seen that on an address claiming it is required to send a claiming packet with 8 bytes of data that compose a thing called 'NAME' (as the picture below), but I did not found any detailed descriptions for each of the bit fields below. And also I don't have a manufacturer code.

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike CAN, in J1939, every device has it's own address. To prevent multiple device having same address, address claiming is must.
If you are confident that the address you will be using is not used by any other device then you may skip the address claim process but it is not recommended.

Address claiming is easy. At start up, you can send address claim message PGN with source address set to your own address. Name can be anything. You may not stick to the standard and send anything as 8 byte. Name comes in picture if another node has same address. Otherwise, it's not really used.
If no other node responds to your address claim message, then you can use that address.
It's more like saying "Is anyone named abomin3v3l here??" If no one responds, you can use that name :-)

About requesting data, you should use request PGN and not RTR bit.
PGN 59904 is used to request data. In that, source address will be your claimed address, destination can be FF (Broadcast) and it needs 3 bytes of data as your required PGN - 00 FE EE in your case.
You should get a response to this request PGN.

Comment: Thanks. But about the NAME, I already have a manufacturer code, the 11 bit field, can the remaining fields be all set to 0 in practice?

Comment: Yes. If it is unique, then sure. Make sure that NAME is unique for the device. If two devices claim same address with same name, then it could be a problem. The problem would be, other devices will not understand that this is coming from two different devices.